# Capacitor at output of component followed by capacitor at input of another component

Tags: capacitor, dc-dc-converter, ldo

I am new to electronics; I want to have an isolated power supply. To do so I use a [DC/DC converter](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/670/pese1_m-1596013.pdf) followed by a [low dropout voltage regulator](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps7a47.pdf).

Both components recommend a certain layout, the DC/DC converter uses a capacitor at its output (C3),

[image]

the regulator at its input (Cin)
[image]

In my design these two components follow each other, I have not made the PCB  yet or the even the schematics, but it is gonna be something like this[image]
should I follow the recommendations of the datasheets and use two capacitors as if I did not know these two components were following each other or should I take into account the fact that C3 and Cin will be in parallel and  only use a single appropriate capacitor with a capacitance value somewhere in the middle ?

For the record C_3's recommended value is 4.7 uF and C_in recommended value is 10 uF, it looks to me like I can not satisfy the two requirements if I do not treat the components independently.

Comment: How are the devices laid out on the PCB?

Comment: @Hearth , I have edited my question, I do not know the details of the PCB, I did not make it yet, I am still considering the components etc...

Comment: Whether you use both capacitors or just one depends on the PCB layout. If they're close enough to each other, they can share a capacitor. If they're on opposite sides of the board, they should probably each have their own.

Comment: Where's the isolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put them very close you can share the capacitor between them.  Use whichever value capacitor is larger.  However, if you're worried about noise to the point where you cascade an LDO after a switching power supply, it is acceptable to leave both in.  In fact, if this is a one-off part I would probably leave in the pad for the second capacitor in case I wanted to test with more filtering.